# Array list or linked list is better to store indexed objects?

Tags: java, arraylist, linked-list

This was on my Java question paper which one out of the two is best to use for a set of indexed  objects? `ArrayList` or `LinkedList` I thought it is `LinkedList`. What is the correct answer and please explain why?

Comment: Define *best* and perhaps the question would be a bit better. What is *best* depends a lot on what you want to do with that list. It's highly likely that the answer is `ArrayList`, but if you want to go to an early index and then remove a bunch of elements (admittedly a rare use case), then maybe `LinkedList` would be better.

Comment: A question about something so fundamental should come with some research (see [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)). _Why_ do you think a linked list would be better? Do you understand how both lists work?

Comment: possible duplicate of [When to use LinkedList<> over ArrayList<>?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/322715/when-to-use-linkedlist-over-arraylist)

Comment: This question has been asked numerous times. For example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/322715/when-to-use-linkedlist-over-arraylist) is very good answer about difference of those two.

Comment: @yshavit "Is Array list or linked list better to store indexed objects?" It is how to ask right? okay. So now it is the question, if I know why? Why I ask others?. Doesn't it better if you could post the answer for, why this should be Linked List or Array List?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Linked lists are not [*random access*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_access); to retrieve an element at some index, you have to traverse the list from the beginning until you reach that index. Arrays (on which `ArrayList` is built), on the other hand, are random access, which means you can simply retrieve an element at a given index in constant time. Therefore `ArrayList` would be more appropriate to store indexed objects.

Answer (score 1):

`ArrayLists` are specifically for indexed data.  `LinkedLists` aren't an indexed data structure.  With an `ArrayList`, you provide the index, the `ArrayList` provides the stored value.  With a `LinkedList`, you have to traverse the list to get the stored value.

Comment: Slight nit: LinkedLists _are_ an indexed data structure, in that each element has an index. They're just not structures optimized for random index probes.

Comment: @yshavit They're definitely an _ordered_ data structure (as opposed to a `Set`, say).  I'd have to look up an exact definition of "indexed" (and I'm sure there are different opinions about that).  But an index in a book enables me to look for something and go directly to the right page without reading sequentially through every other page, so it's hard for me to think of a list that must be traversed sequentially as "indexed".

Comment: @ajb That strikes me a bit like saying that a `Map` isn't a keyed structure if you can't jump directly to an entry (as in, say, a `HashMap` or a `TreeMap`). I don't know that there is a formal definition of an "indexed data structure", but to me it means "one which assigns each entry an (integer) index." The basic methods for a `LinkedList` are `get(int index)` and `set(int index, E element)`; sounds indexed to me. That doesn't mean it has to be efficient to navigate to that index.

Comment: Calling set(index, element) on a LinkedList walks the list to get to that element.  It's not indexed.

Comment: So, does that mean that the `index` there doesn't refer to an index, but to a different concept of the same name? ;)